# Search a line in a string for a number greater than 0

Tags: c++, regex, string

I have a std::string, with a text as such

```
name0 0x3f700000 0x160000 1 0
```

or

```
name1 0x3f700000 0x760000 0 23
```

etc..

What I would like to know is if the last number in this line is greater than 0 and the number before is 1.

I did this but it doesn't work, always it returns a match.

```
std::regex_search(buffer, match, std::regex(std::string("(^|\n)") +  
m_name + " [0-9a-fA-Fx]* [0-9a-fA-Fx]* 1 [1-9a-fA-Fx]*"));
```

Can you say where the error is?  It seems to know when the number before is 1 but that last number seems to be going wrong.

Comment: can there be text after number like `name0 0x3f700000 0x160000 1 0 abcd`?

Comment: no, after the number there is nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[1-9][0-9]*$
```

to check if the number is greater than `0`

**What it does?**

- `[1-9]` Matches `1` to `9`.
- `[0-9]*` Matches zero or more digits
- `$` Matches end of string.

The full regex can be

```
name0 [0-9a-fA-Fx]* [0-9a-fA-Fx]* 1 [1-9][0-9]*$
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/hZ3wF7/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
1\s+[1-9]\d*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE2rP8/1)**

or more specifically

```
^name\d+\s+0x[0-9a-f]+\s+0x[0-9a-f]+\s+1\s+[1-9]\d*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE2rP8/2)**